# Digital Font Puzzle. One easy the other may be not

Tags: calculation-puzzle, no-computers

In the Digital Font shown below, each letter is made up of line segments. For example letter A has 6, B has 7, C has 4 segments and so on.

**Question 1 ( Easy)**

> Which english number, when spelled out (with capital letters) has the
>   same total  number of segments as the number itself?

( It is no fun going through each number. There is some logic here.)

Example : ONE has 6+5+5 = 16 segments

**Question 2 ( Not so easy)**

> Which 2 numbers when added together give you a number same as the
>   total number of segments in those 2 numbers? Ignore + sign segments. This must be other than the first number

Example  :   ONE + ONE = 2 But ONE + ONE = 32 segments not the right answer of course

Surprisingly, I think both answers are unique. No programming please.

[image]

**NO PARTIAL ANSWERS PLEASE. BECAUSE ONE IS EASY**

This puzzle can be linked to

What world is he thinking of?

Comment: Just to clarify, are M and W intended to be 5 or 6 segments each? (They have 6 _line segments_ but two appear to be joined into a single piece.)

Comment: They need to be 6 each

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1:

> THIRTY NINE: 3+5+2+6+3+3 (22) + 5+2+5+5 (17) = 39

2:

> THIRTY EIGHT (22+21=43) + FORTY EIGHT (22+21=43) = 86

Some related curios:

> THIRTY + NINE = THIRTY NINE
>
>  TEN (3+5+5=13) + FIVE (4+2+4+5=15) = FIFTEEN (4+2+4+3+5+5+5=28)
>
>  SEVEN (5+5+4+5+5=24) - FOUR (4+6+5+6=21) = 3

Method:

> I first calculated each number ONE through NINE, TEN through NINETEEN, and then TWENTY, THIRTY, etc...
>
> ```
>  one 6+5+5=16 (15)
>  two 3+6+6=15 (13)
>  three 3+5+6+5+5=24 (21)
>  four 4+6+5+6=21 (17)
>  five 4+2+4+5=15 (10)
>  six 5+2+4=11 (5)
>  seven 5+5+4+5+5=24 (17)
>  eight 5+2+6+5+3=21 (13)
>  nine 5+2+5+5=17 (8)
>  ten 3+5+5=13
>  eleven 5+3+5+4+5+5=27
>  twelve 3+6+5+3+4+5=26
>  thirteen 3+5+2+6+3+5+5+5=34 
>  fourteen 4+6+5+6+2+5+5+5=38
>  fifteen 4+2+4+3+5+5+5=28
>  sixteen 5+2+4+3+5+5+5=29
>  seventeen 24+3+15=42
>  eighteen 21+15=36
>  nineteen 17+3+15=35
>  twenty 3+6+5+5+3+3=25
>  thirty 3+5+2+6+3+3=22
>  forty 4+6+6+3+3=22
>  fifty 4+2+4+3+3=16
>  sixty 5+2+4+3+3=17
>  seventy 5+5+4+5+5+3+3=30
>  eighty 5+2+6+5+3+3=24
>  ninety 5+2+5+5+3+3=23
>  hundred 5+5+5+6+6+5+6=38
> ```
>
> For the single number, nothing less than twenty works so it must be a lexical composite, and a bit of reasoning tells which roughly where to be aiming.
>
>  For the sum, again you can get a rough idea. I hit upon thirty+forty=44. 44 is 26 short of 70, so to add the next numbers we need DF(a+b)=a+b+26. I calculated the excess for each single digit (the number in brackets), and a=b=8 gives my result.
>
>  And now, THIRTY=30-8, and NINE=9+8.

Comment: Other than the first number.

Comment: Did you go through each number or could you find the logic behind? If so, what is it?

Comment: @AmitHagin; I've added an explanation

Answer (score -2):

Answers for Question 1:

> 39

Answers for Question 2:

> 2 and 46
>   2 and 53
>   3 and 52
>   3 and 58
>   4 and 54
>   4 and 57
>   5 and 49
>   6 and 42
>   6 and 48
>   7 and 54
>   7 and 57
>   8 and 46
>   8 and 53
>   9 and 30
>   9 and 45
>   10 and 36
>   10 and 41
>   13 and 52
>   13 and 58
>   15 and 46
>   15 and 53
>   16 and 46
>   16 and 53
>   18 and 40
>   20 and 42
>   20 and 48
>   22 and 40
>   23 and 59
>   23 and 64
>   23 and 67
>   24 and 63
>   26 and 49
>   27 and 63
>   28 and 40
>   29 and 46
>   29 and 53
>   30 and 9
>   32 and 42
>   32 and 48
>   33 and 46
>   33 and 53
>   36 and 10
>   36 and 43
>   38 and 42
>   38 and 48
>   39 and 39
>   40 and 18
>   40 and 22
>   40 and 28
>   41 and 10
>   41 and 43
>   42 and 6
>   42 and 20
>   42 and 32
>   42 and 38
>   43 and 36
>   43 and 41
>   45 and 9
>   46 and 2
>   46 and 8
>   46 and 15
>   46 and 16
>   46 and 29
>   46 and 33
>   48 and 6
>   48 and 20
>   48 and 32
>   48 and 38
>   49 and 5
>   49 and 26
>   52 and 3
>   52 and 13
>   53 and 2
>   53 and 8
>   53 and 15
>   53 and 16
>   53 and 29
>   53 and 33
>   54 and 4
>   54 and 7
>   57 and 4
>   57 and 7
>   58 and 3
>   58 and 13
>   59 and 23
>   63 and 24
>   63 and 27
>   64 and 23
>   67 and 23

Comment: 20+42 and 20+48 also work

Comment: 30+16 isn't a solution